# Error: n() should only be called in a data context( packages conflict)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a calculate column of below data :

```
structure(list(dt = structure(c(18108, 18139, 18169, 17896, 17927,
17955), class = "Date"), nk = c("1-G0175", "1-G0175", "1-G0175",
"1-H0182", "1-H0182", "1-H0182"), ABS_cagr_error_ds = c(16.719,
34.593, 32.696, 9.079, 0.154, 0.998), ABS_arima_error_ds = c(9.804,
13.712, 11.156, 3.212, 9.202, 10.72)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

MAPE_nodes_DS <- temp1 %>%
  group_by(nk) %>%
  summarise(MAPE_arima_ds=sum(ABS_arima_error_ds)/n(),MAPE_cagr_ds=sum(ABS_cagr_error_ds)/n())
```

Error : `Error: n() should only be called in a data context`

So I removed all unnecessary packages and leftover packages are

```
>>(.packages())
[1] "dplyr"    "magrittr" "datasets" "methods"  "base"
```

Here is summary

```
> summary(temp1)
       dt                  nk            ABS_cagr_error_ds  ABS_arima_error_ds
 Min.   :2018-12-31   Length:216921      Min.   :   0.000   Min.   :   0.000
 1st Qu.:2019-02-28   Class :character   1st Qu.:   3.868   1st Qu.:   2.707
 Median :2019-05-31   Mode  :character   Median :   9.818   Median :   5.914
 Mean   :2019-05-23                      Mean   :  18.499   Mean   :   9.061
 3rd Qu.:2019-07-31                      3rd Qu.:  18.195   3rd Qu.:  10.982
 Max.   :2019-09-30                      Max.   :3115.137   Max.   :2281.789
```

I'm not sure what is causing the issue. Can someone help me out? Or is there any other option left for calculating the number of rows without `n()` as this functions is causing the issue?

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue with dplyr 0.8.1 and R 3.6.0 on windows 10

Comment: I did not get an error either, what versions are you using?

Comment: Also could not reproduce. I suggest restarting R, and running your code in a clean session.

Comment: My bad for not specifying, I'm doing in SparkR shell.Yes, I tried several times in new session, still same issue.

Comment: Have you tried calling it this way: `dplyr::n()` or instead `length(ABS_arima_error_ds)`?

Comment: yes @sindri_baldur  no luck : `Error: dplyr::n() should only be called in a data context`

Comment: Try `getAnywhere("summarise")` and see if it finds another one besides `dplyr::summarise`.